# Avoid loading unnecessary data from db into objects (web pages)

Tags: oop, database

Really newbie question coming up. Is there a standard (or good) way to deal with not needing all of the information that a database table contains loaded into every associated object. I'm thinking in the context of web pages where you're only going to use the objects to build a single page rather than an application with longer lived objects.

For example, lets say you have an Article table containing id, title, author, date, summary and fullContents fields. You don't need the fullContents to be loaded into the associated objects if you're just showing a page containing a list of articles with their summaries. On the other hand if you're displaying a specific article you might want every field loaded for that one article and maybe just the titles for the other articles (e.g. for display in a recent articles sidebar).

Some techniques I can think of:

1. Don't worry about it, just load everything from the database every time.
2. Have several different, possibly inherited, classes for each table and create the appropriate one for the situation (e.g. SummaryArticle, FullArticle).
3. Use one class but set unused properties to null at creation if that field is not needed and be careful.
4. Give the objects access to the database so they can load some fields on demand.
5. Something else?

All of the above seem to have fairly major disadvantages.

I'm fairly new to programming, very new to OOP and totally new to databases so I might be completely missing the obvious answer here. :)

Answer (score 1):

(1) Loading the whole object is, unfortunately what ORMs do, by default. That is why hand tuned SQL performs better. But most objects don't need this optimization, and you can always delay optimization until later. Don't optimize prematurely (but do write good SQL/HQL and use good DB design with indexes). But by and large, the ORM projects I've seen resultin a lot of lazy approaches, pulling or updating way more data than needed.

2) Different Models (Entities), depending on operation. I prefer this one. May add more classes to the object domain, but to me, is cleanest and results in better performance and security (especially if you are serializing to AJAX). I sometimes use one model for serializing an object to a client, and another for internal operations. If you use inheritance, you can do this well. For example CustomerBase -> Customer. CustomerBase might have an ID, name and address. Customer can extend it to add other info, even stuff like passwords. For list operations (list all customers) you can return CustomerBase with a custom query but for individual CRUD operations (Create/Retrieve/Update/Delete), use the full Customer object. Even then, be careful about what you serialize. Most frameworks have whitelists of attributes they will and won't serialize. Use them.

3) Dangerous, special cases will cause bugs in your system.

4) Bad for performance. Hit the database once, not for each field (Except for BLOBs).

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of methods to solve your issue.

1. Use Stored Procedures in your database to remove the rows or columns you don't want.  This can work great but takes up some space.
2. Use an ORM of some kind.  For .NET you can use Entity Framework, NHibernate, or Subsonic.  There are many other ORM tools for .NET.  Ruby has it built in with Rails.  Java uses Hibernate.
3. Write embedded queries in your website.  Don't forget to parametrize them or you will open yourself up to hackers.  This option is usually frowned upon because of the mingling of SQL and code.  Also, it is the easiest to break.

Answer (score 0):

From you list, options 1, 2 and 4 are probably the most commonly used ones.

*1. Don't worry about it, just load everything from the database every time:* Well, unless your application is under heavy load or you have some extremely heavy fields in your tables, use this option and save yourself the hassle of figuring out something better.

*2. Have several different, possibly inherited, classes for each table and create the appropriate one for the situation (e.g. SummaryArticle, FullArticle):* Such classes would often be called "view models" or something similar, and depending on your data access strategy, you might be able to get hold of such objects without actually declaring any new class. Eg, using Linq-2-Sql the expression `data.Articles.Select(a => new { a .Title, a.Author })` will give you a collection of anonymously typed objects with the properties `Title` and `Author`. The generated SQL will be similar to `select Title, Author from Article`.

*4. Give the objects access to the database so they can load some fields on demand:* The objects you describe here would usaly be called "proxy objects" and/or their properties reffered to as being "lazy loaded". Again, depending on your data access strategy, creating proxies might be hard or easy. Eg. with NHibernate, you can have [lazy properties](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2010/01/27/nhibernate-new-feature-lazy-properties.aspx), by simply throwing in `lazy=true` in your mapping, and proxies are automatically created.

Your question does not mention how you are actually mapping data from your database to objects now, but if you are not using any ORM framework at the moment, do have a look at [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/) and [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399572.aspx) - they are both pretty solid solutions.